# Windows 7 stuck on starting window

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze, start-screen

my computer with windows 7 got crashed due to opening large number of software files. but when i am starting it again, it is stucking at windows starting screen(screenshot attached). Even when i start in safe mode or safe mode with command prompt it shows following graphical screen and is not moving further. what should i do now?

[image: windows startup screen]

if i open it in safe mode it gets stuck there also. pls see following pic:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you have the Windows 7 DVD, you can try starting with the DVD and doing a Startup Repair.

Comment: i did start up repair but after start up recovery my system became very slow.

Comment: start-up repair can take a very very long time especially for Win7. Your only option is to run it and leave it running overnight.